# Can we use the Core Audio SDK for developing sound effect units for iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio, audiounit, audioqueueservices

There's a so called "Core Audio SDK" which Apple says is for "Mac OS X development". Since there are similarities between Core Audio on the Mac and Core Audio on iOS maybe it's possible to use that SDK for iOS development as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the CA Public sources (`DEV_TOOLS_PATH/Extras/CoreAudio/`) that ship with Xcode: You can use it for some of the things it provides.

Unfortunately, you can't just install and load AudioUnit Effects on iOS like you do on OS X -- if that's what you are getting at…

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an SDK to use CoreAudio, just add the CoreAudio framework to your iOS project in xcode